# How to enable caching for a particular URL with Puppet Apache module?

Tags: puppet, puppetlabs-apache

Using PuppetLab's Apache module, how would I enable caching for a particular URL?  (I'm running a web application that puts all static content under a particular URL)

I understand the resulting configuration line should be `CacheEnable type /foo`, however neither `apache::mod::cache` nor `apache::mod::disk_cache` accept any parameters and from [puppetlabs-apache/templates/mod/disk_cache.conf.erb](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache/blob/master/templates/mod/disk_cache.conf.erb) it appears that including `apache::mod::disk_cache` will enable caching for `/` (which I don't want).

So how would I enable caching for just a particular URL via Puppet?  Should I just use the `concat::fragment` to add the `CacheEnable` directive to the vhost or is there another way to do it?

Comment: As an aside, I have found `mod disk-cache` very disappointing. Using it for *static* content will most likely slow you down instead of helping. Consider `nginx` for delivering these resources instead.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into `nginx`.  The proxy is in front of a Tomcat application and I've heard it's generally best to minimize the JVM's load as much as possible so that's why I was going down this road.

Comment: I ended up using `jfryman-nginx` to configure nginx and I got caching working the way I wanted to.